# Django as backend for React native mobile app, How can we authenticate users with social media signup?

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

Using Django Rest framework we can support mobile apps, for websites Django can authenticate users based on social media using Allauth library. When user signup with Facebook ,a new tab opens and authenticate user with permission.

How can we do this for mobile apps ? I think Standard packages like AllAuth wont support it.

I do not need the codes, but any guidance will be useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django does't have to do anything with it , the app itself can validate

https://blog.expo.io/google-sign-in-with-react-native-and-expo-9cac6c392f0e